# How do I turn all elements on a list into only one int in Python 3?

Tags: python, list

For instance, here is what my list looks like:

```
numlist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How do I turn it into this? --> `numlist [1234]`

Is this possible?

Comment: `[int(''.join(str(n) for n in numlist))]`

Comment: @raschild Not quite. `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: `functools.reduce(lambda m, n: 10 * m + n, numlist)`

Comment: @Ryan Of all the posted solutions, yours is the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print [int("".join(map(str,numlist)))]
```

I would like to convert the list to a string,`join` need a list of string so,`map(str,numlist)`can do this,and then convert this string to integer.

Or use `reduce` method:

```
print [reduce(lambda x,y:x*10+y,numlist)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[sum(10**i*digit for i,digit in enumerate(reversed(numlist)))]
#[1234]
```